# how to define nested dictionary for alamofire POST request

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, post, alamofire

Hi I have a nested dictionary that I need to pass to a function to make a POST request using alamofire.

this is the function that conduct the API call

```
func apiCall(productParameter: [String:String]) {

     AF.request(dataURL, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
            debugPrint(response)
            //some other code here.
        }


}
```

in my viewController, I need to call this function:

```
apiCall(productParameter: [String:String])
```

the problem is I have a very complicated nested dictionary to pass... like this :

```
{
  "userId": "string",
  "price": {
    "currency": "USD",
    "amount": 99.96
  },
  "paymentModel": "string",
  "description": "string",
  "product": [
    {
      "description": "string",
      "name": "string",
      "images": [
        "string"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

do you know how to define the function and data type? thanks.

Comment: Try to use [Codable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types) protocol. Will be much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try `[String : Any]` in this case, so that your keys are always `String`s but the values can be `String`s, `Dictionary`s, `Array`s and so on.

Comment: yes, thanks Eric, I actually figured that out later. using Any you can pass anything you want! awesome!